# How to cast an object to the current PivotItem header

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, binding, pivotitem

I bind a PivotItems with MVVM, and then I try to change the foreground color of the header. The problem is my code worked when I added items programatically only. Now with this binding my headers are of my custom object and I cannot cast it properly:

```
private void Pivot_SelectionChanged(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (0 < e.AddedItems.Count)
        {
            PivotItem currentItem = e.AddedItems[0] as PivotItem;

            if (null != currentItem)
            {
                if (null != currentItem.Header)
                {
                    (currentItem.Header as TextBlock).Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 255, 255));
                }
            }
        }

        if (0 < e.RemovedItems.Count)
        {
            PivotItem currentItem = e.RemovedItems[0] as PivotItem;

            if (null != currentItem)
            {
                if (null != currentItem.Header)
                {
                    (currentItem.Header as TextBlock).Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(64, 255, 255, 255));
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

This line causes problem because now e.AddedItems[0] is not of type PivotItem, but my custom object, so its null..

```
PivotItem currentItem = e.AddedItems[0] as PivotItem;
```

Here is my XAML:

```
<Pivot x:Name="MyPivot" Title="MasterViewModel" Foreground="#FF888888" Style="{StaticResource PivotStyle1}" SelectionChanged="Pivot_SelectionChanged" Margin="0" Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding MyCustomViewModel.Se}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource MyTemplate1}">
        <Pivot.HeaderTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding myProp}" Margin="0, 16, 0, 0" Foreground="#FF888888" FontSize="32" FontFamily="Segoe WP" FontWeight="Light"/>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </Pivot.HeaderTemplate>
    </Pivot>
```

Comment: You are already using DataBinding here. So instead of changing corresponding TextBlock's Foreground value in the code behind, why don't you use binding to change it. Add a property in the VM and bind it to Foreground and in the Pivot_SelectionChanged change value of the property..

Comment: I don't know how to do this, so Id rather stick to my previous solution with the code-behind logic. How can I add property like this?

Comment: Add a property like your "myProp", may be name it "myForeground" and change it in the Pivot_SelectionChanged ..

If you want to do it in the code behind then, what is the Type of object you see for currentItem.Header while debugging ?

Comment: The thing is myProp is defined in the Model, not the ViewModel (its auto-generated). How to do this in the ViewModel? I made a property in the code-behind of the page called HeaderForeground but it doesn't work

Comment: I see. What is the Type of currentItem.Header , can you debug in the code behind and find it out? If it is a DependencyObject you can use the VisualTreeHelper to GetChildren of type Textblock for the Header.